# Kubernetes error when deploying in AWS, how to deploy

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to build a website in AWS using Docker and Kubernetes, however I'm getting the error `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

I don’t have a specific file for Kubernetes, but a folder with all of them. So I'm building on this way:

`docker build .`

`kubectl apply -f ./helm/cognos-proxy-login-chart --recursive`

Docker command completed successfully.

Am I building in the right way? What should I do?

Comment: Seems like your kubeconfig needs some correction. You're probably missing cluster info, if kubectl is trying to talk to the API server on localhost:8080

Comment: I added this information in one of the files in the helm folder

Comment: Did you also tell kubectl where the config is located? You can either set the `KUBECONFIG` env var with the path to the kubeconfig or pass it straight to helm with the --kubeconfig option

Comment: I ran `kubectl config view` and it says no config. I have a config file, how do I set it as config?

Comment: kubectl will look for it under `~/.kube/config`. Alternatively you can set an env var `KUBECONFIG` with the path to the file. [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/)